# Solving four equations with three unknowns

Tags: functions, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

Say I have a function of the form $f(x)=a+b e^{-cx}$, where $a,b$ and $c$ are parameters and $x$ the variable. This function has a decaying gradient after which it asymptotically reaches a value, which are nice properties that I need.

However, I need to engineer my function such that it has a fixed value and gradient at a point $x_0$ and another fixed value and gradient at point $x_1$. In other words

$$
f(x_0)=y_0, \quad f'(x_0)=y'_0 \\
f(x_1)=y_1, \quad f'(x_1)=y'_1
$$

So four conditions. However, my equation only has three parameters. Is it impossible for me to solve for $a,b,c$ such that the function has these properties, or do I need to introduce a fourth parameter? If yes, where does it have to be?

---

In my case I have

$$
f(1400)=0.12941700104175208081 \\
f(4000)=0.26303999997612465328 \\
f'(1400)=0.0002219135984111061086 \\
f'(4000)=1.572054992685082955*10^-6
$$

Comment: As you wrote, $4$ equations for three unknown parameters. You can find a compromise giving a weight to each of the constraints. May be, you could post an example to be worked.

Comment: To illustrate what I wrote in my answer, I would like to get real data from you. Could you add them in the post ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have added some realistic numbers

Comment: This looks like thermochemistry where $x=T$ and $f(x)$ a yield. Am I correct ? Just forget the last condition. Using the three other, you would get $f'(4000)=3.14 \times 10^{-6}$. What is $\pi$ doing here ? $1.572055$ is almost $\frac \pi 2$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'll give it a shot, you are right :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\frac{y_1'}{y_0'}=\frac{f'(x_1)}{f'(x_0)}=e^{c(x_0-x_1)}\Rightarrow c=\frac{\ln(y_1'/y_0')}{x_0-x_1}$$
After that you can use the other properties to get
$$y_1-y_0=f(x_1)-f(x_0)=b(e^{-cx_1}-e^{-cx_0})\Rightarrow b=\frac{y_1-y_0}{e^{-cx_1}-e^{-cx_0}}$$
Now use one of the condition without derivative, for example the first one:
$$y_0=f(x_0)=a+be^{-cx_0}\Rightarrow a=y_0-be^{-cx_0}$$
If we can assume that this value coincides with $y_1-be^{-cx_1}$, then you will be happy!

Comment: OK, but what if not happy ?

Comment: Then there isn't such a function. Maybe you can add $d/x^k$ to $f$ with a fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$. But there's another problem. You can take this approach for $x>0$, but you can improve it with a shift along the x-axis: If a $d/(x-q)^k$ with a fixed $q\in\mathbb{R}$ does help? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in comments, if your model is such, you could find a compromise minimizing
$$\Phi(a,b,c)=w_1(f(x_0)-y_0)^2+w_2(f(x_1)-y_1)^2+w_3(f'(x_0)-y'_0)^2+w_4(f'(x_1)-y'_1)^2$$ the $w_i$'s being weights to be assigned to each of the constraints.

The problem is that none of them will be satisfied exactly.

If I had to do it, I should set $w_1=w_2=1$ and $w_3=w_4=w$ which would make
$$\Phi(a,b,c)=(f(x_0)-y_0)^2+(f(x_1)-y_1)^2+w(f'(x_0)-y'_0)^2+w(f'(x_1)-y'_1)^2$$ and analyze the impact of $w$ upon the results.

For starting the search, use only three conditions as Fakemistake proposed. This should provide pretty good estimates for the minimization.

Comment: This is a very nice approach

Comment: @Fakemistake. Thank you ! Being a physicist, I faced quite often this king of problems. The big question is the value to be assigned to $w$. Only trial and error. It would be good that a set of data be provided in the question in order we can play. Cheers.

Comment: @Fakemistake. Interesting typo in my comment : *king* instead of *kind* !

Comment: This is a nice approach!

Comment: I think it's also possible to use $w_1=w_2=w_3=w_4=1$ and to calculate $\nabla_{a,b,c}\Phi(a,b,c)=0$

Comment: @Fakemistake. For sure. It just depends on how much you want to reproduce the function values and the gradient values. May I confess that I have quite disappointed to see the numbers added to the post. These cannot be experimental values.